# Automatic scaling of WordPress images

Tags: wordpress, image, scaling

I just installed a self-hosted WordPress.org installation, and imported the content from an existing WordPress.com blog. It worked well, except one thing.

The images from the old blog are large. Most of them are 5-10 MB, and they are displayed in full size on the blog, just scaled down in css, making the site extremely slow. Even in the media library in WP Admin, the thumbnails are css-scaled versions of the full size original images.

I thought it might be the import that did not scale or something, but new images I upload have the same problem. On the WordPress.com installation, I see that the images are scaled with query parameters in the image urls, like ...jpg?w=720&h=426&crop=1 (both in wp admin and frontend). In the self-hosted (WP 4.3) installation I just set up, theese query parameters are not added to urls, and if I try to open an image directly and add theese parameters to the url manually, it does not scale down the images.

I have found a bunch of image optimizing plugins, but they just take the full size images and strip away information, set higher jpg compression or other methods to lower the file size by a few percents. Thats not what I want. I want the original full size images to be there for various future uses (like if I change theme to something that needs to show larger images) and then I want the system to scale on demand like described in the WordPress.com installation.

How can I get the scaling on my self-hosted site the same way it works on WordPress.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, php5-gd was not installed on the server. Strange as it was a predefined  Digital Ocean droplet with WP installed.

And strange that WordPress did not inform of it missing, as it made the whole blog unusable, and the media lib almost killed the browser.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress includes several pre-set sizes by default (Full Size, Medium, Thumbnail). You'll have to go back in to your pages/posts and replace the full-size images with one of the alternative sizes:

1. Open the Page or Post
2. Click once on the image to update
3. Click the pencil icon to "Edit"
4. Under "Display Settings" change the "Size" drop-down option
5. Click "Update" button

You can customize the sizes in your theme's `functions.php` file, if you prefer a specific dimension not offered by a vanilla WP install:

`add_image_size( 'Give A Name', 800, 600, true );`

where `Give A Name` is an identifying name for the size, `800` is pixels wide, `600` is pixels tall, `true` is whether to hard crop (`true`) or scale within the dimensions (`false`).

A great plug-in is [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/), which can handle the monotonous task of re-cropping for you if you make adjustments to your sizes.

Comment: Ok, but on the WP.com site, the images are resized to any size using query parameters. Not just some predefined sizes. If I add the same query params to the images on the WP.org site, it doesn't resize the images. Why is that feature only on WP.com?